# What's wrong with the tf.train.match_filename_once or tf.train..string_input_producer?

Tags: tensorflow

[image]

There is no error but I can't get the result. Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post your code here. They [discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code pattern that works. You have to start the queue runners.

```py
filenames = tf.train.string_input_producer(
    tf.train.match_filenames_once("D:/resizedimages/*.png"))

reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
_, input = reader.read(filenames)

input = tf.image.decode_png(input, channels=3)

input.set_shape([299, 299, 3])

init = (tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord) # Start the queue runners

    image = sess.run([input])
    print(image)
```